# Download a zip file that is created when a URL is passed to domain site, but I have tried for 4 days 30-50 different ways, and no luck. CAISO OASIS

Tags: php, file, url, download, php-ziparchive

The site is the CAISO OASIS and they use an old way of querying and returning datasets. 30 days at a time, zip file with enclosed *.csv files. I have tried for 4 days coming up with a way to automate this download first of the zip file but i cant even get past there.

If I populate the url string I want and enter it myself in the address bar a zip file will start downloading, I cannot for the life of me get it to do the same through code.

I need to use php to accomplish this task.
I have tried, fopen, file_get_contents, file_put_contents, cURL, ziparchive class.  I have tried changing all sorts of things. The best I get is a download of a corrupt zip file that is empty.

Ideally i would love to extract the *.csv or xml file but I cannot even do the first basic step.

The following variable I populate, $url_caiso_qry,  if you take the echo string and past in the browser and enter the zip file will start downloading, but I cannot download it automatically.

http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?startdatetime=20220109T7:00-0000&enddatetime=20220207T7:00-0000&resultformat=6&queryname=SLD_FCST&market_run_id=ACTUAL&version=1

```php
<?php

$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public') + 13;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);

// creates data array for precio de carga SIN
// function create_dataarrayp_chrt($zona) {

$ayer = date("Ymd\T7:00-0000", strtotime('now - 1 day')); 
$mespasado = date("Ymd\T7:00-0000",strtotime('-30 days'));


$sdate = $mespasado;  //startdatetime=
$edate = $ayer;   //enddatetime=
$resultformat = '6';
$queryname='SLD_FCST';
$version='1';
$marketrunid='ACTUAL';


$fields = [
    'startdatetime' => $sdate,
    'enddatetime' => $edate,
    'resultformat' => $resultformat,
    'queryname' => $queryname,
    'market_run_id' => $marketrunid,
    'version' => $version,
];

//post fields
$postparam = urldecode(http_build_query($fields));

//PRECIOS   url base string
$urlcaiso = 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?';
//$urlcaiso = 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?resultformat=6&queryname=SLD_FCST&version=1&market_run_id=ACTUAL&startdatetime=' . $sdate . 'T07:00-0000&enddatetime=' . $edate . 'T07:00-0000';

$url_caiso_qry = $urlcaiso . $postparam;

$caisofile = file_get_contents($url_caiso_qry, "rb");

//attempt to write file to destination path, but no file is written.  Instead the following warning
//Warning: file_put_contents(/name1/name2/private/test/):
// failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\name1\name2\private\test.php on line 94

$destination_path = WWW_ROOT . 'name2/private/test/';
$newfile = file_put_contents($destination_path, $caisofile);

echo $newfile . '<br><br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter you pass to file_get_contents describes the `use_include_path` according to the php documentation.

I tried this simple example to get the file and save it:

```php
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?startdatetime=20220109T7:00-0000&enddatetime=20220207T7:00-0000&resultformat=6&queryname=SLD_FCST&market_run_id=ACTUAL&version=1');


file_put_contents('example.zip', $content);
```

Running `file example.zip` gives the following output:
`example.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract` which indicates success.

So essentially your final code could look something like this:

```php
<?php

// Build url here
$url = 'http://oasis.caiso.com/...';

// Download file
$zipFile = file_get_contents($url);

$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/public') + 13;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);

$targetPath = WWW_ROOT . 'proj3-ampenergy/private/test/'; // This could be any other path where your file should be stored

// Write contents to file
file_put_contents($targetPath, $zipFile);

// Write extraction logic here
```

Comment: I have received this before as well.   and i do not understand exactly what it means.   i have been in php.net reasearching for 3 days trying to uncover what all these errors and warnings mean and i cannot figure out, why this is happening.  I get the following Warning with no file saved to the target path.          Warning: file_put_contents(/name1/name2/private/test/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Your `$targetPath` variable needs to point to a location where a new file can be created. You could test your code by writing the new file to `/tmp/example.zip` and later on change `$targetPath` to a location you want to actually store the file later on.

Comment: there is nothing in that folder now.  nothing is being written to it.    i set the following to $targetPath =  '/name1/name2/private/test/20220108_20220206_SLD_FCST_ACTUAL_20220208_20_49_09_v1.zip'               nothing was written, but there was no error and no warning.  i will check the dev tools in chrome.                          Waiting (TTFB). The browser is waiting for the first byte of a response. TTFB stands for Time To First Byte. This timing includes 1 round trip of latency and the time the server took to prepare the response.

Comment: Your path points to an invalid location (As your path starts with `/` it's assuming you are starting from your system root). Try to remove the `/` in the beginning so `$targetPath` starts with "name1/name2" and make sure that the directory structure name1/name2/private/test actually exists before trying to write to it.

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(name1/name2/private/test/20220108_20220206_SLD_FCST_ACTUAL_20220208_21_05_53_v1.zip): failed to open stream: No such file

Comment: You need to pass in the path as a string, that's why I originally put the path into a variable which somewhat enforces you to use a string. so you need to do `file_put_contents("xxx", $zipFile);`

Comment: Thank you all for you help.   I feel like the biggest nube right now.......   I defined a constant DOWNLOAD_PATH for the target directory appended the targetfile name to it and it downloaded the file.     Thanks  
Bl00D4NGEL for having me see the light as I search again on the stream issue and it had to do with the fact that my defined constant WWW_ROOT was not defined correctly,   So I went back and defined a defined a new CONSTANT to an absolute path.  i will be able to modify to relative path once on a live webserver.  Now I will move on to writing the extraction phase of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Clean & tested code. Your csv file will be extracted to your script's directory.

```
<?php

define('PATH_ZIP', __DIR__ . '/archive.zip');

$url = 'http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?' . http_build_query
([
    'startdatetime' => '20220109T7:00-0000',
    'enddatetime'   => '20220207T7:00-0000',
    'resultformat'  => '6',
    'queryname'     => 'SLD_FCST',
    'market_run_id' => 'ACTUAL',
    'version'       => '1',
]);

$data = file_get_contents($url);

file_put_contents(PATH_ZIP, $data);

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open(PATH_ZIP) === true)
{
    $zip->extractTo(__DIR__);
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check today.  I researched the failed open socket and the comments above and realized I was in my mind defining the correct directory but I needed to pass the abosolute path of the target location as it was a  string.    Thank you for your post, i will use for the extraction phase of the zip files.